# Shuffle order of names pulled from mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, random, shuffle

Im sure this is not to hard, but I cant seem to figure it out on my own.

I have a mysql db with a list of names, and im using the following to assembile the names into a comma seperated list.

```
$emailresult = mysql_query("SELECT * from leaddist")
        or die(mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($emailresult)){
        $repemail .= $row['email'] . ", ";
        }
        echo $repemail;
```

this outputs something like:
name1, name2, name3, name4, name5

my question is, what are some methods to shuffle that into:
name3, name1, name4, name5, name2

then when executed again, it would be something like
name 4, name1, name2, name5 and so on......

Comment: On a sidenote ... dont use the php legacy mysql connector ... use mysqli or PHP PDO instead

Answer (score 7):

You can use mysql for this:

```
SELECT * FROM `leaddist` ORDER BY RAND()
```

Note that this can be performance critical if the table is **really** large but should suite well for small to medium sized tables

Comment: Glad that I helped you. Yeah, 5 rows can be considered *small sized* ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to retrieve the SQL already randomized:

```
SELECT email
FROM leaddist
ORDER BY RAND()
```

**Note:** if you only need the email column, you should specify it in the query. Try to avoid the use of * in selects.

Comment: Well it was just an example, the idea was the same anyways.

Comment: Don't worry you didn't even need to upvote it. Yours is the most accurate one, but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're going about it wrong. You're building a string. You should be building an array, then use the built-in PHP [shuffle](http://php.net/shuffle) function:

```
$emails = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($emailresult)){
    $emails[] = $row['email'];
}
shuffle($emails);

$repemail = implode(',', $emails);
```